# conflicts between cpu and arch while building

Tags: gcc, arm

I have a doubht regarding mcpu and march options of gcc.
In my setup the environment variables are using -mcpu=cortex-a7 and -march=armv7ve, while building application getting the following error.

```
error: switch -mcpu=cortex-a7 conflicts with -march=armv7-a switch [-Werror]
```

Actually cortex-A7 uses armv7-a architecture. Not sure why getting this conflict issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though it's true that a Cortex-A7 uses the ARMv7-A architecture, it's also true that a Cortex-A7 implements extended features that are not implemented by all ARMv7-A processors; more specifically, a Cortex-A7 implements the ARMv7ve variant.

In general, specifying both -mcpu and -march in gcc options is redundant, because -mcpu (which tells the compiler to generate code that will run on a specific processor) implies -march (which tells the compiler to generate code that will run on a specific architecture or variant). If you only care that your program must be able to run on a Cortex-A7, you can use -mcpu=cortex-a7; if your program must be able to run on any ARMv7-A processor, you must use -march=armv7-a (optionally adding -tune=cortex-a7 if you want the code to be optimized for Cortex-A7 while still being able to run on other processors).